# Plugin/Custom Code to email me when a plugin update is available

Tags: wordpress

I've tried 2 or three plugins but none seem to be functional. Is there a custom code piece out there or somewhere I can implement a PHP script that will send me an email when a new plugin update is available? Currently have tried WP Update Notifier and Mail-on-Update with zero success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/).

Set `Email summary frequency` to daily.

Use `Scan for out of date plugins, themes and WordPress versions` to find plugin updates.